# Why do I have several instances of "Player"?

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I am developing an android app that has a music player functionality. Everything is working now as it should be but I am not happy with the way I did this so here I am.

The app is 100% kotlin 100% compose. I am using a NavHost for navigation between composable screens. [image: Here is a very badly diagram with the parts that are related to what I am interested]

The Main Activity holds the NavHost.
The NavHost holds all the navigation and composables per screen

Each screen (well, not every one of them but most) I am using a PlayerScaffold that is passed a top bar and a content and them composes the screen normally but adds and updates a bottom mini player (a la spotify) and a full screen modal player that swipes up.

Each content screen has its own viewmodel and the mini player and the full player has a PlayerViewModel.

The PlayerViewModel gets passed an instance of "Player" that is a class that holds the exoplayer instance and does all the playing things.

The Player class is instantiated by Dagger Hilt and defined in a module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class PlayerModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindPlayer(
        playerImpl: PlayerImpl,
    ): Player
}
```

On top of that I have a Foreground Service "PlayerService" to hold the "Player" instance for when the app goes to background so it can hold the reference to the player and does not get killed.

The issue I was having (solved now) is that several instances of the PlayerViewModel and the Player were being created and therefore If I start playing a song in one screen, and go to the next, the player in the next screen would not update properly. I solved it by holding an instance of the PlayerViewModel in the Application class so only one gets created but I am **very** unsure of this approach.

The way I expected it to work is each compose screen would have an instance of the PlayerViewModel, but the instance of Player would be the same for all ViewModels.

Why am I having several instances of the Player class if it's annotated as "Singleton"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the issue here was in the PlayerModule class I annotated it as

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
```

and me not reading documentation assumed that that meant that it automatically would make everything in that module "Singleton"

Adding @Singleton to the function solved the issue. No need to keep instances of viewmodels anywhere, now it works as expected.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class PlayerModule {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindPlayer(
        playerImpl: PlayerImpl,
    ): Player
}
```